# Example for Database architecture

Tags: databases

PHPMyadmin is stated as a 3 tier database architecture.How is  this possible,Isn't it a 2 tier architecture.What are the real world examples of 1-tier and 2-tier architecture.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is on-topic here: questions about specific products or software packages might not be suitable. Any community votes one way or another?

Comment: I think this is more appropriate for software engineering (this site is more theory-focused I think). https://example.net is literally 1-tier since all accessible content are directly public.

Answer (score 1):

*The short answer:*

You're right, it is a 2-tier architecture.
A 1-tier architecture doesn't allow the database to be run on a separate host. *phpMyAdmin* does, so it is 2-tier; but not 3-tier.

*The long answer:*

I've Googled for examples of this claim and ended up at [this webpage](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/architecture-of-database.php), which says:

> In the 2-tier architecture, we have an application layer which can be
> accessed programatically to perform various operations on the DBMS.
> The application generally understands the Database Access Language and
> processes end users requests to the DBMS.
>
> In 3-tier architecture, an additional Presentation or GUI Layer is
> added, which provides a graphical user interface for the End user to
> interact with the DBMS.
>
> For the end user, the GUI layer is the Database System, and the end
> user has no idea about the application layer and the DBMS system.
>
> If you have used MySQL, then you must have seen PHPMyAdmin, it is the
> best example of a 3-tier DBMS architecture.

While this distinction is certainly useful, this is not what is usually meant by a 3-tier architecture. To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture):

> N-tier application architecture provides a model by which developers
> can create flexible and reusable applications. By segregating an
> application into tiers, developers acquire the option of modifying or
> adding a specific layer, instead of reworking the entire application.
> A three-tier architecture is typically composed of a presentation
> tier, a domain logic tier, and a data storage tier.
>
> While the concepts of layer and tier are often used interchangeably,
> one fairly common point of view is that there is indeed a difference.
> This view holds that a layer is a logical structuring mechanism for
> the elements that make up the software solution, while a tier is a
> physical structuring mechanism for the system infrastructure.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)
> For example, a three-layer solution could easily be deployed on a
> single tier, such as a personal workstation.

... and further down:

> Generally, the term "tiers" is used to describe physical distribution
> of components of a system on separate servers, computers, or networks
> (processing nodes).

So in order to be 3-tier, it is not enough for *phpMyAdmin* to have a GUI that allows the user to manipulate databases without typing SQL. It must separate its GUI from its application logic (the code that actually implements its functionality) into two different *layers*, such that the application logic really is a separate layer: it can be tested separately, a completely different user interface can be written on top of it as an alternative to the GUI, etcetera.

[The phpMyAdmin code base](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin) doesn't do this. You can see this by looking at [libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php), which contains utility functions that the rest of the phpMyAdmin code bases uses to communicate with the database.
This is what is used to perform an SQL query:

```
/**
 * runs a query
 *
 * @param string $query               SQL query to execute
 * @param mixed  $link                optional database link to use
 * @param int    $options             optional query options
 * @param bool   $cache_affected_rows whether to cache affected rows
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function query(
    string $query,
    $link = self::CONNECT_USER,
    int $options = 0,
    bool $cache_affected_rows = true
) {
    $result = $this->tryQuery($query, $link, $options, $cache_affected_rows);

    if (! $result) {
        Generator::mysqlDie($this->getError($link), $query);

        return false;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Note how it calls `Generator::mysqlDie` - which is a function that generates HTML.
So executing SQL queries and generating HTML (which is presentation) are mixed together in the same function. It is impossible to put a command-line interface on top of this code, it would need to be rewritten first.

So the *phpMyAdmin* code can't be separated into 2 layers. Even if it could, 2 layers aren't 2 tiers: 2 tiers can be *physically* separated: they can be run on different machines with the presentation tier connecting over the network to the application tier.

Some general lessons to take away from this:

1. IT people tend to be incredibly sloppy with jargon. When 10 authors use a term, they probably mean at least 5 different things with it. Be especially wary when it comes to jargon used to sell expensive IT to managers; *3-tier architecture* is a prime example. Never trust anything written on IT at face value. Always wonder - as you're doing with this question - whether what you're reading uses terms in a more or less standard way. Or whether there *is* a standard way in the first place. Apply this caution to *anything*: articles on websites by random people on the internet, books published by popular IT publishers, lecture notes from famous universities. All authors bend terms to fit their own needs and preconceptions.
2. Wikipedia articles on IT are just as bad as the rest, on average, or worse; but sometimes, they are pretty good. This one is pretty good - today (who knows what it will look like one year from now).

Answer (score 0):

"3 tier database architecture" is a bit of misnomer, as database by itself doesn't have extra tiers. So what are the 3 tiers? From outter-most to inner most, they are:

1. presentation,
2. application processing,
3. data management.

https://example.net is literally 1-tier since it doesn't have application processing and data management, it just presents a text permitting you to use that domain name in documentations.

FTP would be a 2-tier protocol since it doesn't have application processing.